# PayPal DoCapture in Sandbox fails with 10609 error - Invalid TransactionID

Tags: paypal

Paypal's Sandbox API responds to a DoCapture with "Invalid TransactionID" error code 10609. The same operation works correctly in the PayPal live site.  I think there might be some deprecated params that are rejected in the Sandbox, but accepted in the PayPal live site.

The ff. is POST data from IPN:

`[mc_gross] => 1.05
    [auth_exp] => 05:28:33 May 26, 2016 PDT
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [payer_id] => SCBNBBCFDWQ54
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payment_date] => 05:28:33 Apr 26, 2016 PDT
    [payment_status] => Pending
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [first_name] => SandboxStephen
    [option_selection1] => Lc1tCoAwCAbgu3iCxtYHdpghtEKoUc2IEd09G_ulPq8oYYtPwh7hSuH0PMGYlMCYbrB_r8kUaK2JRXCuqc7JLzzLPxmEogPCcVEUllzZlKq-U95CFL-QhJtyPagb-ub9AA,,~7634f
    [transaction_entity] => auth
    [option_selection2] => VU7LDgIhEPuX-QACw_CavfoHxjPZAAdNBLO4h43x3wXjxfYybZNOVyZ-dUaG6wOWzooYnBZIQSiDQqH8upphvbe9PmMtJZcMS2YlpJF_ICLpA8rgR2DRqsFABq11qK1Gr9D82tK-baWmI6aWy3wxvMv5NC83tvR4661OJRlgeX8A~97b17
    [option_selection3] => S7QytKoutjK3UspNLS5OTE9Vsi62MrBSUrKuBQA,~2c5b4
    [option_selection4] => S7QytqoutjK3UkrPTCuJL8lXsi62MrBSAlGWUMG0ovxcJGFDA6h4am5iZg5cohYA~2aa63
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [custom] => 
    [payer_status] => verified
    [business] => xxxxxxx@xxxxx
    [quantity] => 1
    [verify_sign] => AvzodxdQ1l47jbnC5iCE7iEjAVYEAnMT6fQE9TdHnShf4zX8V6L99Kpe
    [payer_email] => xxxxxx@xxxx
    [option_name1] => Transkey
    [parent_txn_id] => 
    [option_name2] => Syskey
    [option_name3] => Message
    [option_name4] => Gift
    [txn_id] => 4R146799GX924083N
    [payment_type] => instant
    [remaining_settle] => 10
    [auth_id] => 4R146799GX924083N
    [last_name] => xxxxx
    [receiver_email] => xxxxxxx@xxxxx
    [auth_amount] => 1.05
    [shipping_discount] => 0.00
    [insurance_amount] => 0.00
    [receiver_id] => F3XAHZBJYATHU
    [pending_reason] => authorization
    [txn_type] => web_accept
    [item_name] => Test New Deal 2 (Topic)
    [discount] => 0.00
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_number] => 
    [residence_country] => US
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [shipping_method] => Default
    [handling_amount] => 0.00
    [transaction_subject] => 
    [payment_gross] => 1.05
    [auth_status] => Pending
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [ipn_track_id] => ff07a74b6ad10`

The ff. are parameters for DoCapture:

`[authorization_id] => 4R146799GX924083N
    [amount] => 1.05
    [invoice_id] => 9569
    [currency] => USD
    [CompleteCodeType] => Complete
    [note] => Acuerdo de pago`

The ff. is PayPal's response to DoCapture:

`[AUTHORIZATIONID] => 4R146799GX924083N
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2016-04-26T12:28:57Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 82d81683c3cc8
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 62
    [BUILD] => 21669447
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10609
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid transactionID.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Transaction id is invalid.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error`

I have tested the new PayPal security upgrades on the site and they work correctly.  I specify a very old version (62) of the API, so that might be the problem, but I don't see what I need to change to get the Sandbox to work correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you mix up the sandbox environment and live environment. You call DoCapture in the live environment, but the 4R146799GX924083N transaction is generated in sandbox environment.
When you call Docapture API, please make sure the API endpoint is https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp , the endpoint change to sandbox , not live.

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887028/create-paypal-sandbox-merchant-seller-account)

Comment: That was my problem.  Due to a code bug, I was doing the authorize in the sandbox and the capture in the live site. Thank you so much.